# How to dynamically change REST API URL in Azure Data Factory Copy Tool?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm new to Data Factory and I need to pull data from a Rest API to SQL database. I can set this up with static URL, but the API URL needs the current date time and other criteria to be updated dynamically. For example, I have this API URL:
https://api.something.com/2021-03-23T00:00:00Z/
The "2021-03-23T00:00:00Z" should be changed dynamically for the current datetime every time it's triggered. I'm not sure how to set this up. Please help!

Comment: Maybe you can add dynamic content `@concat('https://api.something.com/',utcnow())` at **URL** tab.

Comment: Hi @virtual.learner. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add dynamic content `@concat('https://api.something.com/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'),'Z')` to the URL tab.

The output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Joseph! That works to concat the URL, but it threw an error of  Failed to validate the signature because the content is tampered

Comment: Sorry I failed to reproduce your problem. Can you post a new question?

Comment: Hey Joseph, sorry for the delay. Finally was able to work with MS support team, and we fixed the issue. For me, in the linked service, the base URL set to "https://api.something.com". Then in the pipeline source request body, that is where to put the concat string without the base url "@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')"